# Test is touchesMoved: still inside SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, sprite-kit

**UPDATE**
I have solved the problem with following code:

```
- (BOOL) isInside:(NSSet *)touches
{
    //NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
    BOOL isInside = NO;

    //NSLog(@"touchLocation %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchLocation) );
    //NSLog(@"self.position %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.position) );
    //NSLog(@"self.frame    %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame) );
    //NSLog(@"self.size     %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.size) );

    CGFloat atlX = fabsf(touchLocation.x);
    CGFloat atlY = fabsf(touchLocation.y);

    CGFloat lenX = self.size.width  / 2;
    CGFloat lenY = self.size.height / 2;

    if ( (atlX <= lenX) && (atlY <= lenY) ) {
        isInside = YES;
    }

    return isInside;
}
```

**Original Question**

This code I used for my subclass of UIView:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
    BOOL isInside = [self pointInside:touchLocation withEvent:event];

    if (isInside)
    {
        if (NO == _isAlreadySelected)
        {
            [self setAppearanceSelected];
        }
        else
        {
            [self removeAppearanceSelected];
        }

       // more code
    }
}
```

Now I have class that is subclass of SKSpriteNode, so I wanted to use same logic:

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
BOOL isInside = [self pointInside:touchLocation withEvent:event];
```

But it is not working, I can not compile. (because these method do not exist for `SKSpriteNode`).
I manage to change first line to:

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
```

**Question**
But how to fix:

```
BOOL isInside = [self pointInside:touchLocation withEvent:event];
```

for `SKSpriteNode`

**UPDATE**
Current solution with help from @duci9y

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
    BOOL isInside = [self containsPoint:touchLocation];

    NSLog(@"touchLocation %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchLocation) );
    NSLog(@"self.position %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.position) );
    NSLog(@"self.frame    %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame) );

    if (isInside)
    {
        NSLog(@"INSIDE");
        //self.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:_onImage];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"OUTSIDE");
        //self.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:_offImage];

    }
}
```

LOGS:

```
-[WOC_OnOffImageButton touchesBegan:withEvent:]
touchLocation {9.5, 18}
self.position {160, 440}
self.frame    {{138, 414.5}, {44, 51}}
OUTSIDE
```

To me it look like that there is some problem with coordinate system between SpriteKit and UIView. e.g. they do not start from same point (bottom-left vs. top-left).

Answer (score 0):

[Read the docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/containsPoint:)

```
BOOL isInside = [self containsPoint:touchLocation];
```

Comment: This method exist and when I add it code can compile, but I have found new problem. With current code every touch is OUTSIDE the `SKSpriteNode`even when it is inside. I think that problem is in  `[self containsPoint:touchLocation]` because previous call on UIView was `[self pointInside:touchLocation withEvent:event];` it used this `event`. Any idea how to detect ?

Comment: @WebOrCode Log your node's dimensions and position and the point returned by `locationInNode:` and update your question with the results.